# test-kitchen command not found

Tags: docker, chef-infra, test-kitchen, kitchen-dokken

I'm trying to test chef recipe locally using test kitchen docker, I installed chef workstation, chef, and test kitchen but kitchen still complaints "Kitchen not found"

```
-bash: kitchen: command not found
```

Here's what I installed on my redhat7 linux machine ;

```
Chef Workstation version: 22.1.778
Chef Habitat version: 1.6.420
Test Kitchen version: 3.2.2
Cookstyle version: 7.31.1
Chef Infra Client version: 17.9.26
Chef InSpec version: 4.52.9
Chef CLI version: 5.5.6
```

**kitchen.yml**
---
driver:
name: docker

```
provisioner:
  name: dummy

verifier:
  name: inspec

tranport:
  name: docker

platforms:
  - name: centos-7
    docker_config:
        image: centos:7
        platform: centos

suites:
  - name: default
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/integration/default
```

**Error:**

```
kitchen list
-bash: kitchen: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute `kitchen --version` and see the output. It should output you the version of the Test Kitchen if correctly installed

Eg:

`kitchen --version`
`Test Kitchen version 3.x.x`